# Proving that the cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, and thus it is a rectangle.

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

Let us say that we have a circle and a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ where the segment $BD$ passes through the center of the circle, thus being the diameter. Also, $\angle A$ and $\angle C$ are both right angles.

We also have a triangle $DEB$ where the measure of $\angle E$ is $90^\circ$.

The measures of $\angle EBD$ and $\angle DBC$ are $30^\circ$ and $20^\circ$ respectively, making $\angle B$ add up to $50$.

My job was to simply prove that $ABCD$ is a rectangle.

My intuition is that $ABCD$ is definitely a rectangle, since two opposite angles of the quadrilateral are both right angles in the first place. (However, my picky math teacher wants me to even justify this statement.)

This way, I took a different approach, initially proving that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, thus it is a rectangle. (Since we already have a pair of opposite right angle triangles, where two angles that are left have to be both equal to each other and adding up to $180^\circ$, making $90^\circ$ the only answer.)

However, my end game is to prove that the line $AC$ passes straightly through the center of the circle just like $BD$. In this way, I can't prove that the cyclic quadrilateral is a parallelogram since there is a possibility that $AC$ doesn't pass through the center, contradicting the property that two diagonal lines should bisect each other which only works when $AC$ is a diameter, getting bisected into two radii.

Would this be the case where there is not enough information to perform the proof?
I have tried to come up with many different premises and theorems, but in the end, I find myself back to square one.

[image: The diagram image. (Sorry, my new account doesn't have 10 reputations yet.]

Comment: By the way ... To get an accurate GeoGebra figure where some segment $PQ$ is known to be a diameter of a circle with center $O$: put $P$ wherever you like on the circle, then construct $Q$ on the opposite side of $O$ by using the "reflect [P] about point [O]" command.

Comment: Welcome ! +1 for well written Question ! Like your "picky math teacher" , I want to high-light some Issues (1) We can talk about $\angle A$ & $\angle C$ to refer to Quadrilateral , like-wise $\angle B$ will refer to Quadrilateral , hence it is wrong to state $\angle B = 50$ , you have to write $\angle EBC = 50$ (2) We can state $\angle A$ is right angle or $\angle A$ measures 90 , we should avoid writing $\angle A$ measures right angle. (3) There is confusion about which Diagonal goes through Center (4) Either way , it looks like $ABCD$ may not be Parallelogram : Some Criteria may be missing.

Comment: @Blue hello, thanks for your correction. Yes, it is the segment BD that passes through the center in the premise and the original question had a typo.

Comment: The Angle **E** being $90°$ and given other angles "30°" and "20°" give no additional information about the quadrilateral,Because Even After changing the other two angles, And maintaining angle "E" to be 90°,It will have no effect on quadrilateral ABCD by any means,So it essentially does not give out any information

Comment: You are right , @DheerajGujrathi , I think that Point $E$ was given to guide students towards seeing that $\angle A$ will always be $90^\circ$ , no matter where $A$ is ! More Details in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently , $ABCD$ may or may not be Parallelogram , unless we have Extra Details.

Consider these Counter Examples :

Point $A$ could be $A1$ or $A2$ or $A3$ & all Cases will give angle $90^\circ$.

These Quadrilaterals will all satisfy the given Criteria , yet might not be Parallelograms. There may be a Parallelogram among those Points though that is not yet known here.

[image: COUNTER EXAMPLES]

Your "Picky" teacher was right to ask for Proof for your Claim : The Claim was actually wrong.

ADDENDUM :

I used well-known theorems to conclude that the various angles are all $90^\circ$ : Details are available here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle