# Is there any way to prove that something not provable due to insufficient information?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Just like the title states, would there be any way to logically justify that there is insufficient information given by the problem, so thus it is impossible to give one definite answer?

**In [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814526/proving-that-the-cyclic-quadrilateral-abcd-is-a-parallelogram-and-thus-it-is), there was the following premise:**

We have a circle and a cyclic quadrilateral 
where the segment 
passes through the center of the circle, thus being the diameter. Also, ∠
and ∠
are both right angles.

We also have a triangle 
where the measure of ∠
is 90∘.

The measures of ∠
and ∠
are 30∘
and 20∘
respectively, making ∠
add up to 50.

From the question, my job was to prove whether it is possible to find the angle ∠BDA (where I primarily had the approach of first proving that the quadrilater ABCD is a rectangle, which thus automatically makes the angle 20∘).[image]

While consulting with some users, I saw people almost unanimously stating there is not enough information. One response, by @Prem, really stands out where he stated, **"Point 
could be 1
or 2
or 3
& all Cases will give angle 90∘.
These Quadrilaterals will all satisfy the given Criteria , yet might not be Parallelograms. There may be a Parallelogram among those Points though that is not yet known here."**
[image]
This way, I am also pretty convinced by the idea that the question is unverifiable. However, I think it is rather subtle for me to logically demonstrate and prove how the question is insufficient to prove.

I can say that there are literally infinite cases that could be drawn only based on the information given, and this way, it is impossible to prove just like the diagram above which draws a several possible cases that still satisfies the condition.
However, I am not sure whether this fact itself is enough to "logically" justify that it is unfalsifiable. Would there be any proof by contradiction or an expression which can successfully perform this?

Comment: The argument is that $A$ can be anywhere on the semicircle, allowing multiple values for $\angle BDA$.  If $A$ is near $B$ then  $\angle BDA$ is close to $0^\circ$, while if $A$ is close to $D$ then $\angle BDA$ is close to $90^\circ$, and all intermediate values are possible by continuity.  Just two different values are sufficient to show there is no unique solution: if $ABCD$ is a rectangle then  $\angle BDA=20^\circ$ while if $A$ is at $E$ then $\angle BDA=60^\circ$, both of which you have shown.